# Rollover hex code to show color thumbnail

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there a setting where I can have the color thumbnail to show next to the color hexcode? Or is there a way in dreamweaver that I can quickly know the colors of the hexcode?

Sometimes when I rollover the hex code, it shows the color thumbnail but there are times when it is either veryyyyy slow to popup or it doesn't show at all. */*This can chew some nerves.*/*

Is it due to a certain setting I missed or it is a by default behaviour? How can I have it show right next to the hex code?

Answer (score 0):

You are working in the code view? Usually when you select the hex code in the stylesheet it will give you a quick view (thumbnail/icon) of the color, and even allow you to alter it.

Comment: it is very slow to popup especially if I want to check a few colors at one go. Is there a setting to have it just show right next to the hex code without the need to hover over the hexcode?

Comment: No, I do not think such a setting exists... but I did find this tedious note in a forum:

To actually launch the color picker, one has to:

Right click in the color
Scroll to the very bottom of the modal menu
Select "Code Hint Tools"
Select "Color Picker" from the options

Comment: Thanks @midnightMaurader. I'm using the latest version of Dreamweaver but can't find the 'Colour Picker' from the right click menu. Nonetheless, thanks to your tip, I found the shortcut to quickly launch the color. `cmd+e`. Not what I want but at least this works faster than waiting for the pop up to appear.